# Slow Performance after fixing Geforce driver problem

Tags: 12.04, resolution, screen, performance

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on Asus K43; Memory 5.8 G.B.; Processor Intel core i7 CPU@2.00 GHZx8; Graphics: GeForce GT 540m/pcie/ssf2; OS type: 64 bit and Disk 26.4 G.B. I faced a problem (Black Screen) after updating my Geforce driver. The issue has been solved using the following command jockey-text -e xorg:nvidia_current,however, the system performance seems considerably slow comparing it with the previous state (before the Geforce driver problem) specially at start up it takes more time than before and the resolution is less as well. Is there away to fix this please? Regards.

Comment: As is, the question is very vague to be answered meaningfully. Can you edit the original question and provide more info on what was the problem, how you fixed it, hardware specs.

Comment: We definitely more info on the original issue and how it was fixed. at this point I can only speculate. I can tell you that Asus puts linux drivers on their recovery CDs.. so, maybe grab drivers from there?

Comment: Please take a look at this link (http://paste.ubuntu.com/1278329) , probably will give you what you are looking for as for what happened, while I already wrote the command line used to solve this. How, why, what, or why is still beyond my personal experience into Linux yet. I hope this will help you to help me.

Answer (score 1):

I've received an automatic update which includes a driver update for Geforece that initiated the problem from the first place. After this automatic update things turned to be as good as it was before the problem took place affecting the performance after being solved.